# Check Page Request Source

Tags: url, security

Working on a data collection application using mobile sms.

when a customer send a sms lets say 
SMS content

> Demo CET 100-50030-2320-1000

when the sms reach the mobile serive provider it send a GET request on my server

> http://domainname.com/demo.aspx?mno=9828958745&sms=CET+100-50030-2320-1000

Now the problem is some hackers are sending GET request from there PC browser and all the data is getting missed and server is getting overload

I want to know which request is from a computer(mobile server) and which are from browser.

thanks in advance
Regards

Check if the request for a page is coming from a server not a browser.

Comment: Yeah and I would like a magic wand that allows me to summon donuts.  We don't always get what we want,  especially when what you want is totally impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your service is not meant to be accessible publicly you have to protect it instead of publishing it on the internet. Some wasy to protect it:

- HTTP Authentication
- IP restrictions in firewall.
- IP restrictions in the service.
- Virtual Private Network.